# Android virtual device emulator - strategy advice needed.

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm switching over from eclipse to Android Studio and have 2 machines available. One with VX-t hardware support and one without.

I'd like to try the machine without virtualization hardware support and would appreciate some feedback on the current state of affairs regarding google development tools.

1. Is it fair to say that debugging using the emulator (without VX-t) is still (essentially) unusable?
2. I am considering bypassing the emulator and just using a real device. Besides being limited to a single device type, what are the pros and cons of this strategy?

Thank you and kind regards.

Comment: Have you considered GenyMotion? https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: I read about GenyMotion just today and will consider using it after further research. I was hopeful that google had optimized the emulator recently with the release of their new IDE. Thank you for responding.

Comment: From: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide

"Genymotion implies that you have the following hardware on your computer:
VT-x or AMD-V capable CPU, enabled in BIOS settings;"

since it was suggested I will give it a try, assuming that it will still work without hardware support, just a bit more slowly...